# Blender API and Kinnect

Tags: python, scripting

I am writing some app to control Blender by gestures using MS Kinect. I saw few examples, like adding cubes etc, but i would like to know is there an option to use API to change view, rotate or move object smoothly as doing it by mouse. I know that i can use for example:
    bpy.ops.view3d.view_pan()
but it will happen instantly, not as doing it by mouse.
The second question is can I use Blender API to execute python scripts one after other. I mean, is there option to run script by external program, not by clicking in blender "run script"? This is necessary if I want use Kinect without using keyboard or mouse.Thank you in advance for your answer and I'm sorry for my English :)

Comment: Welcome to Blender.se @Pocisk... Can you please ask two separate questions? thx

Comment: At the request of @Polosson:
I decided to use console to execute commands, so i can move objects smoothly by for example using     `bpy.context.object.location.x += 0.1` few times per second but: 
Is there opt

Comment: At the request of @Polosson:
The second question is not importnat because I decided to use console to execute commands, so i can move objects smoothly by using for example
    `bpy.context.object.location.x += 0.1` 
few times per second but: 
Is there an option to do the same with perspective?

Sorry for the mess with previous comment, I'm not familiar with forums.

Comment: Maybe `bpy_extras.view3d_utils.region_2d_to_vector_3d()`?
It returns a direction vector from the viewport at the specific 2d region coordinate. (basically 2d viewport space to 3d space)